# Check that a specific radio button is checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, shoulda

I'm performing some tests on a form with radio buttons. I have a radio button that has the following identifiers:

```
<input checked=​"checked" class=​"radio_buttons optional" id=​"rating_commute_8" name=​"rating[commute]​" type=​"radio" value=​"8">​
```

I'm trying to get it to pass the following test, but it is giving me the error `Failure/Error: within(:css, '#rating_commute_8').should be_checked LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)`:

```
  within(:css, '#rating_commute_8').should be_checked
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `within` method is used for scoping where to look for an element. For example, you might want to only look for the radio button in a certain div:

```
within(:css, '#some_parent_div') do
  find(:css, '#rating_commute_8').should be_checked
end
```

In this case, assuming the radio button's id is unique, you do not need to define a specific search scope. You just need to find the element and then check if it is checked. To just find the element, you need to use `find` instead of `within`. The following should work:

```
find(:css, '#rating_commute_8').should be_checked
```

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of rspec/capybara without shoulda it would look like this:

```
within('form') do
  expect(page).to have_checked_field('rating_commute_8')
end
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one, as well, since it should wait for such a field to exist / be checked before failing (if, for instance, you have an ajax request or it gets checked in some other dynamic way).